# I want to change the contents of the array with multiple flags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the contents of an array with multiple flags in JavaScript.

I have data like below.

```
export const sample = () => {
    const sampleValue = [
        {
            text: "aaaa",
            name: "aaaaaaaa"
        },
        {
            text: "bbbb",
            name: "bbbbbbbb"
        },
        {
            text: "cccc",
            name: "cccccccc"
        },
    ];

    return flag1
    ? [
        ...sampleValue,
        {
            text: "ddddd",
            name: ”dddddddd"
        }
        : sampleValue;
    ]
}
```

Include the following **only when flag2 is true**.

```
        {
            text: "bbbb",
            name: "bbbbbbbb"
        },
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. . If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: flag1 or flag2? what is the problem? Use a filter

Comment: keep it simple. `if (flag1) result.push(whatever)`, `if (flag2) etc`

Answer (score 0):

```
    [
      ...array, 
      ...flag1 ? [ {text: '', name: ''} ] : [],
      ...flag2 ? [ {x: '', y: ''} ] : [],
      ...flag3 ? [ {hello: '', world: ''} ] : []
    ]
```

You got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not quite sure what you want to do...
I hope this will help you:

```js
const array = [{
    text: "aaaa",
    name: "aaaaaaaa"
  },
  {
    text: "bbbb",
    name: "bbbbbbbb"
  },
  {
    text: "cccc",
    name: "cccccccc"
  },
];

const flagObj = {
  text: "bbbb",
  name: "bbbbbbbb"
}

const newObj = {
  text: "ddddd",
  name: "dddddddd"
}

const sample = (arr, flag, add) => {
  let res = arr.filter(obj => obj.text === flag.text && obj.name === flag.name);
  if(res.length) { // Only when arr has flag
    arr.push(add); // Add new value(object) to arr
  }
  return arr;
}

sample(array, flagObj, newObj);
console.log(array);
// Output:
// [{
//   name: "aaaaaaaa",
//   text: "aaaa"
// }, {
//   name: "bbbbbbbb",
//   text: "bbbb"
// }, {
//   name: "cccccccc",
//   text: "cccc"
// }, {
//   name: "dddddddd",
//   text: "ddddd"
// }]
```